# type inference still need enhance,any better suggestion for this example?

Tags: scala, clojure

for instance in Clojure:

```
user=> (map #(* % 2) (concat [1.1 3] [5 7]))

(2.2 6 10 14)
```

but in Scala:

```
scala> List(1.1,3) ::: List(5, 7) map (_ * 2)

<console>:6: error: value * is not a member of AnyVal
       List(1.1,3) ::: List(5, 7) map (_ * 2)
                                       ^
```

Here ::: obtain a list of type List,oops then failed. Can any coding more intuitively like Clojure above?

Comment: It would make your question a little easier to read if you used the code formatting features of Stack Overflow.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Clojure is dynamically typed, which makes type inference unnecessary or done at runtime, depending on your perspective. One of the advantages of flying without a net.

Comment: This is one of the disadvantages of subtyping. In a more flexible type system like Haskell's, the type of `3`, for example, is neither `Double` nor `Int`, but `(Num t) => t`, where `Num` is any ring implied by the integers.

Comment: To follow on to Apocalisp's point, there are several discussions of typeclasses in Scala. Enough, in fact, that you should do a Web search for "Scala typeclass" if you're interested in the techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Here are you individual lists:

```
scala> List(1.1,3)
res1: List[Double] = List(1.1, 3.0)

scala> List(5, 7)
res2: List[Int] = List(5, 7)
```

The computed least upper bound (LUB) of `Double` and `Int`, needed to capture the type of the new list that includes elements of both the arguments lists passed to `:::`, is `AnyVal`. `AnyVal` includes `Boolean`, e.g., so there are no numeric operations defined.

Answer (score 2):

As Randall has already said, the common supertype of Double and Int is AnyVal, which is inferred in this case. The only way I could make your example work is to add a type parameter to the second list:

```
scala> List[Double](1.1,3) ::: List(5, 7) map (_ * 2)
:6: error: value * is not a member of AnyVal
       List[Double](1.1,3) ::: List(5, 7) map (_ * 2)

scala> List(1.1,3) ::: List[Double](5, 7) map (_ * 2)
res: List[Double] = List(2.2, 6.0, 10.0, 14.0)
```

I guess that in the latter case the implicit conversion from Int to Double is applied. I'm not sure why it this not applied in when adding the type parameter to the first list, however.

Answer (score 1):

The first list is of type `List[Double]` because of literal type widening. Scala sees the literals, and notes that, even though they are of different types, they can be unified by widening some of them. If there was no type widening, then the most common superclass, `AnyVal` would be adopted.

```
List(1.1 /* Double literal */), 3 /* Int literal */)
```

The second list is clearly `List[Int]`, though explicit calling for `Double` will result in type widening for the literals.

```
List(5 /* Int literal */, 7 /* Int literal */)
```

Now, it's important to note that type widening is something that happens at *compile* time. The compiled code will not contain any `Int` 3, only `Double` 3.0. Once a list has been creater, however, it is not possible to do type widening, because the stored objects are, in fact, different.

So, once you concat the two lists, the resulting type will be a superclass of `Double` and `Int`. Namely, `AnyVal`. As a result of Java interoperability, however, `AnyVal` cannot contain any useful methods (such as numeric operators).

I do wonder what Clojure does internally. Does it convert integers into doubles when concatenating? Or does it store everything as `Object` (like Scala does) but has smarter math operators?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to make it work - braces for the second part

```
scala> List (1.1, 3) ::: (List (5, 7) map (_ * 2))
res6: List[AnyVal] = List(1.1, 3, 10, 14)
```

or explicit Doubles everywhere:

```
scala> List (1.1, 3.) ::: List (5., 7.) map (_ * 2)  
res9: List[Double] = List(2.2, 6.0, 10.0, 14.0)
```

which is of course semantically different.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just,

```
(List(1.1,3) ::: List(5, 7)).asInstanceOf[List[Double]] map (_ * 2)
```

?